# Excel table Lookup values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a table-1 like this:

```
NAMES     ID     
John      1
Bill      2
May       1
Silvia    1
Sam       3
Oren      2
```

Another table-2:

```
ID_To_Compare   name1     name2     name3
1
2
3
```

I would like to have in table-2 function that gets result like this, according to ID_To_Compare (seeks it in table-1):

```
ID_To_Compare    name1     name2     name3
1                John      May       Silvia
2                Bill      Oren
3                Sam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample data:

[image]

Formula in cell `B10`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$7=$A10,ROW($A$1:$A$7),""),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down and right...

Answer (score 1):

An Excel lookup looks like this;

```
=VLOOKUP(I7;Sheet1!$A$2:$F$250;2;FALSE)
```

- The first part (`I7` in this case) is the value of the key to find.
- The second part (`Sheet1!$A$2:$F$250` in this case) is the range to search in.
- The third part (`2` in this case) is the column index of the queried range from which the value should be read.
- The last boolean tells whether or not it is a range lookup (in this case we're after a single value).

Comment: I know VLOOKUP. It only gets one value. I need multiple values, that are also transposed from rows to column.